# Изменение направления градиента во время выполнения программы

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, градиент

Пишу небольшую программку, в которой можно просматривать двухцветные градиенты, написав небольшую основу решил добавить вращение градиента по перетаскиванию мыши с нажатой ЛКМ и столкнулся с проблемой.

Значения StartGradient и EndGradient меняются во время выполнения программы, поэтому в Gradient они указаны как динамичные ресурсы. На этом этапе все хорошо.

Теперь нужно изменять значения StartPoint и EndPoint в Gradient, следовательно в GradientBackground он должен быть указан как динамичный ресурс.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="StartGradient">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="EndGradient">Black</Color>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Gradient" StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource StartGradient}" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource EndGradient}" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="GradientBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource Gradient}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Изменяю направление, например, так:

```
((LinearGradientBrush)Application.Current.Resources["Gradient"]).StartPoint = new Point(1, 0.5);
((LinearGradientBrush)Application.Current.Resources["Gradient"]).EndPoint = new Point(0, 0.5);
```

Направление изменяется, но не изменяются цвета полученные от StartGradient и EndGradient, когда это нужно. А если в GradientBackground поставить StaticResource, то получится обратная ситуация - будут изменяться цвета, но не будет изменяться направление градиента.

Comment: Почему бы не завести 2 `LinearGradientBrush`, а в стилях контрола по триггеру выбирать нужную?

Comment: @aepot, предполагается, что направление может быть любым (точки StartPoint и EndPoint всегда будут противоположными)

Comment: В одном моем проекте, мне нужен было обычный цвет превратить в градиент, где снизу был чуть темней оттенок, то есть некий эффект объемности. Решил я такую задачу при помощи простого расширения разметки (MarkupExtension) [таким образом](https://pastebin.com/FLd6Aj02), использование было `Background="{Binding Color, Converter={con:ColorToGradient}}"`, то есть как простой конвертер и из за того, что там есть конструктор, ему можно задать все эти значения динамически. Короче я бы сделал примерно такой же код для вашей задачи.

Comment: Со `StaticReasource` у вас как раз работают объекты `GradientStop`, а с `DynamicResource` - нет. Ставьте `StaticResource`, и нужно менять не `StartPoint` и `EndPoint`, так как они влияют только угол заливки, по ним он высчитывается. А нужно менять `Offset` у элементов коллекции `.GradientStops`.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513892/how-to-bind-gradientstop-colours-or-gradientstops-property-in-silverlight/1513978), посмотрите еще вариант с конвертерами, под SilverLight правда, но именно эта часть совместима с WPF.